# Pandas: parse columns from csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in csv file without header. I need to parse some columns.

A part of data:

```
-1.0,-0.0246259814315,1174.60023796
 1.0,-0.978057706084,1083.19880269
-1.0,0.314271994507,-1472.97760911
-1.0,0.179751565771,231.017267343
1.0,-1.26254374278,-778.271726463
-1.0,0.249969939456,-52.8014826538
1.0,-1.87039747875,-324.235348241
```

I need to load only second and third columns. I use `train_X = pd.read_csv("perceptron-train.csv", sep=',', parse_dates=[1], usecols=[2, 3])` but it returns `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: you need to enclose square brackets: `train_X = pd.read_csv("perception-train.csv", parse_dates=[1])`  also for usecols you should pass a list of either the names or ordinal positions of the columns

Comment: Use `parse_dates=[1]` and keep in mind that the column-indices are zero-based.

Comment: @EdChum if I want to scecify two columns I should use two brakets?

Comment: @ldevyataykina no this is a list. You separate them by a comma

Comment: Sorry you mean something like: `train_X = pd.read_csv("perception-train.csv", parse_dates=[1], usecols=[1,2,3,4])`, if you want to parse multiple columns for dates then you pass a list of the cols: `train_X = pd.read_csv("perception-train.csv", parse_dates=[1,2])` if you want to parse multiple columns to create a single date column because one column is the date and the second is the time then you need double brackets: `train_X = pd.read_csv("perception-train.csv", parse_dates=[[1,2]])`

Comment: @EdChum can you say, my columns separate with `,`, i use `train_X = pd.read_csv("perceptron-train.csv", sep=',', parse_dates=[1])` but it return me 3 column, not one

Comment: You still need to pass `usecols=[1]`: `train_X = pd.read_csv("perceptron-train.csv", sep=',', parse_dates=[1], usecols=[1])` also by default the separator is comma already so you don't need it. `parse_dates` just instructs which cols to try to parse into datetime, `usecols` is what tells pandas which columns to actually read and load, by default it's all columns

Comment: @EdChum it returns `IndexError: list index out of range` but all data looks like this string `-1.0,-0.0246259814315,1174.60023796`

Comment: Please can you edit your question with raw data, your code and the desired output, I and others have repeatedly asked you to do this for the majority of your questions, also the data you posted doesn't look like a datetime string so I don't see what you're trying to do here

Comment: @EdChum I add data to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC indices are zero-based so you need:

```
train_X = pd.read_csv("perceptron-train.csv", sep=',', parse_dates=[1], usecols=[1, 2])
```

Also I don't know if this also means you need to change your date col:

```
train_X = pd.read_csv("perceptron-train.csv", sep=',', parse_dates=[0], usecols=[1, 2])
```

However, looking at your data I don't understand how to interpret the first or second column as a datetime as they look weird